Navigate locally an index html containing a 3D art carousel
Whenever I launch the program live from Visual Code, it works as intended.  The issue I have is running the code locally when I navigate from the index file in the file folder.
I'm positive the issue is within the index file, but I can't find the issue.  The program is supposed to show a 3d art carousel in the html page with the images below.
The issue is when I launch the index file in the pc folder to see if it runs in the browser.  Prior to this, I run the code live through Visual code and the program worked as planned.  I assumed it would work if I launched through the index file after importing the files to a server.  Despite this, the html page only displays a single still image blow-up beyond proportions.
I can't quite single out what I'm failing to include despite researching the issue from similar postings.  There's obviously something I'm missing in the index page.
[text](http://hccwebdev.net


 var angle = 0;
function galleryspin(sign) { 
spinner = document.querySelector("#spinner");
if (!sign) { angle = angle + 45; } else { angle = angle - 45; }
spinner.setAttribute("style","-webkit-transform: rotateY("+ angle +"deg); -moz-transform: rotateY("+ angle +"deg); transform: rotateY("+ angle +"deg);");
}
div#carousel { 
  perspective: 1200px; 
  background: #100000; 
  padding-top: 10%;
  padding-bottom: 30%; 
  font-size:0; 
  margin-bottom: 3rem; 
  overflow: hidden; 
}
figure#spinner { 
  transform-style: preserve-3d; 
  height: 300px; 
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -500px; 
  transition: 1s; 
} 
figure#spinner img { 
  width: 40%; max-width: 425px; 
  position: absolute; left: 30%;
  transform-origin: 50% 50% -500px;
  outline:1px solid transparent; 
}
figure#spinner img:nth-child(1) { transform:rotateY(0deg); 
}
figure#spinner img:nth-child(2) { transform: rotateY(-45deg); }
figure#spinner img:nth-child(3) { transform: rotateY(-90deg); }
figure#spinner img:nth-child(4) { transform: rotateY(-135deg); }
figure#spinner img:nth-child(5){ transform: rotateY(-180deg); }
figure#spinner img:nth-child(6){ transform: rotateY(-225deg); }
figure#spinner img:nth-child(7){ transform: rotateY(-270deg); }
figure#spinner img:nth-child(8){ transform: rotateY(-315deg); }
div#carousel ~ span { 
  color: #fff; 
  margin: 5%; 
  display: inline-block; 
  text-decoration: none; 
  font-size: 12rem; 
  transition: 0.6s color; 
  position: relative; 
  margin-top: -18rem;
  border-bottom: none; 
  line-height: 0; }
div#carousel ~ span:hover { color: #888; cursor: pointer; }
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<header>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>3D Carousel</title>
  <base href="F:\College assignments\Summer 2024\Web Scripting with Java\cop2830\p7\images\Enchantress of the Haze.jpg">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="F:\College assignments\Summer 2024\Web Scripting with Java\cop2830\p7\style.css">
</header>
<body>  
  <div id="carousel">  
  <figure id="spinner">
    <img src="Seed of the Haze.jpg" alt="Seed of the Haze">
    <img src="Daughter of the Haze.jpg" alt="Daughter of the Haze">
    <img src="Enchantress of the Haze.jpg" alt="Enchantress of the Haze">
    <img src="Primeval Ruins.jpg" alt="Primeval Ruins">
    <img src="Ruins.jpg" alt="Ruins">
    <img src="Fish Creature.jpg" alt="Digital fish creature">
    <img src="Fish Creature.png" alt="Digital fish creature 2">
    <img src="Leviathan Hunter.jpg" alt="Leviathan Hunter">
  </figure>
  </div>
  <script src="F:\College assignments\Summer 2024\Web Scripting with Java\cop2830\p7\main.js"></script>
</body>
<span style="float:left" class="ss-icon" onclick="galleryspin('-')">&lt;</span>
<span style="float:right" class="ss-icon" onclick="galleryspin('')">&gt;</span>
</html>



/~scripting130/p7/index.html)
Edit:  I believe I was able to fix the issue as the program appears to function now after my last import attempt.  I noticed that when I was importing the folder to the remote site, something was failing to import.  It just so happened to be the image folder.  I think removing the folder and bundling the images with the other files acted as a workaround since the image folder would fail to import for reasons.
http://hccwebdev.net/~scripting130/p7/index.html

@Teemu My apologies.  So the code is for a 3D art carousel that should run in the browser.  The issue I have is when I launch the program from the index file in my pc folder, the html page only shows the images blown-up on the page as shown "http://hccwebdev.net/~scripting130/p7/index.html".  The file should display a 3D carousel with the images that you can navigate through with two arrow keys "left and right" at the bottom.

Look in the console and network tab Your style.css is not found

@mplungjan Ahh, well I'm not sure how I missed that.  I might have been experimenting with the file path and was trying to see if that fixed it before posting.  The image shows now, but still having the same issue as before.  The carousel not showing and just a big blown-up image.  I notice the carousel showing in the code preview snippet, but of course not the images.

@mplungjan I changed the href from "/style.css" to "style.css"

I edited the file paths again and pasted the file path suggested by Visual Code.  Now the program functions as intended locally, but not when exported to a host for live viewing.

I think I fixed the issue.  http://hccwebdev.net/~scripting130/p7/index.html

I had to experiment a bit with how the file paths were inserted into the code and arrange the files around.  I removed the images folder and clumped the image resources with the index, main and css.  Not particularly organized, but it appears to work now.
